# What is the C# equivalent of this VB6 Rnd() call?

Tags: c#, random, vb6, vb6-migration

I am having a problem with the VB code `Int(Rnd() * 75) + 75)` conveting it to C#.
I have tried

```
Random random = new Random
random.Next( 75 ) + 75
```

But its isnt right. Please Help me.

Thanks

Comment: what is the intent? do you want between 75, 150 or something else

Comment: I actually have no idea how the VB code works, ive got to translate the VB code to C#, but when i use the code that ive tried it randoms numbers in the thousands.

Comment: Jon skeet answer is correct. CInt(Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd() + lowerbound)) in VB translate to rand.Next(lowerbound,upperbound) in c#. (From [documentation of Rnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that's meant to give a value between 75 (inclusive) and 150 (exclusive) I'd use

```
Random random = new Random();
int value = random.Next(75, 150);
```

That's clearer than first generating a number in the range [0, 75) and then adding 75, IMO.

Note, however, that you *shouldn't* be creating a new instance of `Random` every time you want a random number. You probably want one instance per thread. I have a [reasonably long article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) explaining the various pitfalls in generating random numbers, and some workarounds.

Comment: +1 for the link. May i know why Guid.NewGuid cannot be used to generate random numbers (apart from performance issues)

Comment: What is the default range that the VB Rnd() uses?

Comment: @Tilak: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/30/guid-guide-part-two.aspx for Eric Lippert's explanation of GUIDs and randomness.

Comment: @Sigh-AniDe: I just did a search for "vb rnd function" and found [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2.aspx) which states that it's greater than or equal to 0, but less than 1. You could have done the same search :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I actually did alot of searches but couldnt figure out how to get that code in C# :? How would you put greater than or equal to 0, but less than 1 in a C# random?

Comment: Think ive got it random.Next(0,1);

Comment: @Sigh-AniDe: No, because that would give you an *integer* greater than 0 or less than 1 - basically, it would always give you 0. You want `random.NextDouble()`.

Answer (score 3):

See your code in VB is doing

1. Generate a random number.
2. Multiply it with 75 and convert it into int.
3. Then add 75 in it.

In C# its like

```
Random random = new Random();
int v = random.Next() * 75 + 75;
```

No conversion required because `random.Next()` gives an integer. More over you can limit your random number generation by providing min and max value b/w which to find out like this:

```
random.Next(50, 100);
```

where it will only find random number b/w 50 and 100.

Comment: `Next` returns an integer so you would never get anything different from the calculation, meaning your convert is pointless.

Comment: @Likur and Ash : Thanks and Corrected

Answer (score 1):

I think it like this

```
        Random random = new Random();
        int rdnum = (random.Next() + 1) * 75;
```

**EDIT**

At last if i need his random i will use this (0-20 for smaller numbers)

```
        int rdnum = ((new Random()).Next(0, 20) + 1) * 75;
```

**EDIT2**

After comment of Deanna, code will be

```
        Random random = new Random();
        Double rdnum = (random.NextDouble() * 75) + 75;
```

Comment: In begin he asked Int(Rnd() * 75) + 75) so numbers can be 75, 150, 225 etc. I agree with @NikhilAgrawal's Answer but imho my code more nice to use.

Comment: But as i said, @NikhilAgrawal's answer is best suits the question

Comment: @likurg: VB6's `Rnd()` returns a float between 0 and 1, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if you want exact Rnd function you can follow these steps:
1.In Solution Explorer, right click on references and click "Add Reference..."
2.In Assemblies -> Framework, check the checkbox of "Microsoft.VisualBasic"

Now you can use it like this:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBMath.Rnd();
Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBMath.Randomize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note that `Random Rnd = new Random();` should move out of for...loop in some cases:

```
Random Rnd = new Random(); 
float fRnd = (float)Rnd.NextDouble() * 75f + 75f;
```